# Drawing multiple images using paintComponent()

Tags: java, image, swing, draw

I would like to display more than one image on the screen in the same `JPanel`.

A for loop iterates over each element in the array and displays their corresponding image, but only seems to keep the last image.

The code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class GameGUI extends JFrame{
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
int arrayLength;

public GameGUI() {
    super("Gameplay");

    //Set size of the frame.
    setSize(650, 580);
    //Location inside frame.
    setLocation(10, 8);

    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread();
```

The methods that contain each individual panel:

```
    createMainPanel();
    createCentrePanel();
    createNorthPanel();
    createSouthPanel();
    createWestPanel();
    createEastPanel();
    setVisible(true);

}
//creating panels

public void createMainPanel() {
    //here is the main panel which the others will be nested in.
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    add(mainPanel);
}

public boolean createCentrePanel() {
    JPanel CENTRE = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    CENTRE.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    CENTRE.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    mainPanel.add(CENTRE, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return true;
}
```

This is the panel which i am using to print multiple images to the panel.
As you can see I have a for loop which is going through each item in the array and passing the value to the draw component. However it only seems to keep the last image on the screen eventhough each item in the array is being passed to it.

I have tried using `repaint` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public boolean createNorthPanel() {
    int[] array = {1, 8, 9, 10};
    arrayLength = array.length;
    int size = 0;
    JPanel NORTH = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    NORTH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    NORTH.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    mainPanel.add(NORTH, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        NORTH.add(new drawPanel(array[i], size, arrayLength));
        size = size + 30;
        //repaint();
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean createSouthPanel() {
    JPanel SOUTH = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    SOUTH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    // SOUTH.add(new drawPanel(2, 0));
    // SOUTH.add(new drawPanel(5, 30));
    SOUTH.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    mainPanel.add(SOUTH, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    SOUTH.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    return true;
}

public boolean createWestPanel() {
    JPanel WEST = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    WEST.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
    //WEST.add(new drawPanel(8, 0));
    WEST.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    mainPanel.add(WEST, BorderLayout.WEST);

    return true;
}

public boolean createEastPanel() {
    JPanel EAST = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    EAST.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
    EAST.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    mainPanel.add(EAST, BorderLayout.EAST);
    //EAST.add(new drawPanel(2, 0));
    //EAST.add(new drawPanel(7, 60));

    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new GameGUI();
}
}
```

Here is my class which draws the images on the screen

```
class drawPanel extends JPanel {

Image image = null;
int xPos;

public drawPanel(int x, int y, int length) {

    xPos = y;
    try {
        File location = new File("src/Card_images/" + x + ".png");
        image = ImageIO.read(location);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}

/*public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
 return new Dimension(71, 96);
 }*/
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //draws image to screen at positions displayed
    g.drawImage(image, xPos, 0, this);
}
}
```

Comment: It would help if your code was runnable.

Comment: i just added the import files to the above code. Additionally it should just be images that are missing.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16221416/300257 for an example of how to ask a question that involves images.

Comment: Have you run it under debugger?  Your loop does not have a "wait" state. Is it possible that it just runs so fast that you do not notice how images are changing?

Comment: The images shouldnt change they should all display on the screen but it only displays the last image.

Answer (score 3):

You only have a single drawImage() statement that is executed in you paintCompent() method so you only ever see the last image drawn.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two different ways to draw multiple objects. You will obviously need to customize for your requirements, but the basic concepts will be the same.

Edit:

The above does not apply to your question, but is still good to know when you do need to do some custom painting.

Sorry, because of the custom painting I misread your question. You are making the code too complex.

The first problem is that you changed the layout manager of the "north" panel to a BorderLayout. You can only add a single component to any location of a BorderLayout. So that is why the last component added gets painted. Just use the default FlowLayout for the panel. Although your code still won't work because your components don't have a preferred size.

So the solution to your problem is:

a) create a panel using a FlowLayout
b) Use a JLabel to display your images. There is no need to do custom painting!. Add the labels to the panel, then add this panel to your frame.

Now the layout manager can do its job and you don't need to worry about the details.

Also, use standard Java naming conventions. Your code is too hard to read because you don't follow the standards.

- NORTH is not a proper variable name. It should be "north". An upper cased name indicates a final static variable.
- use proper class names. Classes should start with an upper case character. "drawPanel" should be "DrawPanel".

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to put `repaint()` inside `drawPanel()` method after `image` is assigned its value? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PM77-1: There is no `drawPanel()` method; you may have been misled by the unconventional class name and constructor.

Comment: @camickr - OK. It's a constructor. But my question stands. OP has a loop that creates new panels. Has constructor that retrieves files and stores them in Image. Has `paintComponent` to draw this image that would respond to `repaint`.  What seems to be missing is the `repaint()` call itself.

Comment: @PM77-1, repaint() does nothing when the panel is not displayed on a visible GUI. The code would seem to imply that all these panels are being built before the GUI is visible. I misread the question. See my edit.